# Ruby microservices - how to restart / respawn in production

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, microservices, production

I'm currently in the process of moving some Rails functionality out into some microservices, I shan't bore you with the reasons for this, suffice to say we're happy with the decision and our architecture choices.

At the moment it is not particularly complicated, a handful of standalone scripts running, talking via rabbitMQ, all with a few gem dependencies (bunny, mysql2 etc) when I fire them off via the CLI it all works great.

My problem and where I require some advice, is how to move these to daemons that can be automatically respawned on failure.

Our current platform is as follows:

Centos 6.5 (Don't ask)
RVM 2.5.1@somegemset
nginx
passenger
someuser

For Rails I use Capistrano, with the RVM and Bundler plugins and it is fire and forget, everything gets deployed, if it falls over it gets restarted and away we go.

I originally thought I could just add each ruby microservice into the init directory with respawn. But the jobs would never start.

If I connect as another user (not the rails someuser) I get gem/rvm issues. So I thought it may be a path problem, in an attempt to resolve it I thought we could lose rvm and go with bundler install --binstubs.

This works from the command line eg. service_directory/bin/bundle exec service.rb

but still doesn't work in init, they just fail starting with a status 42 (?) here is my init conf.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting shutdown

respawn

exec /home/someuser/services/some-service/bin/bundle exec /home/someuser/services/some-service/lib/service.rb
```

I tried with chdir to keep it neater but no joy there either.

I have tried to use foreman, works fine with foreman start but the upstart export scripts created fail in the same manner.

I've tried making them executable with the rvm ruby wrapper as a shebang, the scripts include

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```

I've read about monit but that seems to want pids which my scripts don't produce.

I am sure I am missing something as there must be an easy way to allow any user (including root and system users) to hit any script and for the gems to be found and the thing to run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future me, and anyone who finds it useful.

I resolved it by using the god gem. The upstart script was still a massive pain, I couldn't get it to just work how I would have liked, but I did manage to get it to work by using RVM wrappers.

The final upstart script looks like this. It's important to not that I tried to load multiple god configs using *.god, but this would only load the first one. In the end I just put each config block in one file, as recommended elsewhere, which got us in the game.

/home/someuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.5.1@agemset/god -D -P /var/run/god --log /var/log/god.log -c  /home/someuser/services/master.god

It's not ideal. It's interesting that you have to run it as a foreground process, even though it is within upstart, but taking out the -D didn't work.

If god dies, the child scripts don't die, which is a bit of a nuisance. I suspect there is a way to kill off the services, but that is for another day.

It will at least kick off the god process on reboot, and God will take care of keeping the services up.